# Cannot wake from suspend - GNOME 17.04 on a NUC6CAYH

Tags: usb, 17.04, wakeup, intel-nuc

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on a NUC6CAYH a couple of weeks ago. It works pretty well except one annoying thing, which is I cannot wake the computer from S3 sleep state. After failing to find answers on the web I decided to ask it here.

I guess it can be due to Intel BIOS in which there is no option like 'wake from S3 with USB'.
On the other way I can bet that others bought this computer to run Ubuntu and I am surprised it is reported nowhere.
The only way I found to work to wake from S3 was by pressing the power button during just the right amount of time: A shorter press will not work, a longer press will force the shutdown of the machine.

The output of the command below is a bit confusing to me, as I cannot see any USB device

```
ju@nuc-ju:~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
SIO1      S3    *disabled  pnp:00:00
HDAS      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:0e.0
XHC   S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:15.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
BRCM      S0    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.1
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.2
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I only found that XHC, XHCI, EHCx or USBx are USB devices (X versions are USB3), but they are already enabled...